# how to connect to mysql database from gui made in python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have used Tkinter to create radiobuttons  through which I would like to increment by one in the database after the submit button is clicked  whenever a radiobutton is checked.

Most important i would like to connect to MySQL database but I don't know what to add in my script.

```
from Tkinter import *
root= Tk()
frm=Frame(root,relief=RAISED,borderwidth=5,bg="green" )
Label(frm,text= "PLEASE SELECT CANDIDATE\n OF YOUR CHOICE\n\n\n\n",bg="green").pack()
var = IntVar()
for text, value in [('YOWERI KAGUTA MUSEVENI', 1), ('KIIZA BESIGYE', 2), ('AMAAMA JOHN MBABAZI ', 3),
('KARUNGI SHARON', 4), ('BYAMUKAMA OSCAR', 5),
('MATILDA MOREEN', 6), ('DUNCANS', 7)]:

 Radiobutton(frm, text=text, value=value, variable=var,padx=18,bg="green"
 ).pack(anchor=E, fill=X, padx=18 )
 var.set(0)
frm.pack(pady=10)
btn=Button(frm,text='submit',fg="black",bg="yellow")
btn.pack(anchor=E)
root.title("movie chooser")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's the relationship between those button items and your DB? Are you trying to perform insertion, deletion , display or... ?

Comment: Updating the table whenever the raiobutton is selected and submit button is pressed.update by incrementing by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to guide you step by step to resolve your problem. I assume you have already installed MySQL server on Ubuntu.

Whether you are using Tkinter or some other GUI package, the method to implement your goal remains the same.

## What tools do I need to use?

First, you will need to to install a Python database interface that will allow you to communicate with MySQL server using Python. Here is the exhaustive [list of Python MySQL databse interfaces](https://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL).

Which one is better to install? I prefer to talk only about 2 of them that I used myself: [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/) and [MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/).

MySQLdb is rather a C library which makes  it faster than MySQL connector which is a pure Python library. For portability it is better to choose the later one. For speed you need to choose the first one. Note that [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) uses MySQLdb. That is also my favorite database interface I am going to use in what follows. You can find a good comparison between these 2 interfaces [here](http://charlesnagy.info/it/python/python-mysqldb-vs-mysql-connector-query-performance).

## How to install MySQLdb on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

The common way to install MySQLdb is to use [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) as described [here](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/how-to-set-up-mysql-for-python-on-ubuntu/). But for Ubuntu, by my personal experience, I prefer to install it this way:

- Install the needed dependencies: `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libmysqlclient-dev`
- Install the MySQL databse interface itself: `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`.

Now you should be able to import it:
`>>> import MySQLdb`

## Interface design

First, we'll ask the user to type his  credentials to MySQL server:

[image]

If the credentials are wrong, the window still prompts itself there unless the user exists the application.

If the credentials are the right one, the user may then save/add his favorite starts to the database through a new window similar to the one you designed:

[image]

## Implementing the application:

**1. Database design:**

I choose the simplest one, just to satisfy this immediate need:

`mysql> CREATE DATABASE begueradj;`

Now it is time to create the table in which we save your favorite stars. It will contains their names `starname` and an auto incrementing primary key `id`:

```
mysql> USE begueradj;
mysql> CREATE TABLE mystars(id INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                            starname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY(id)
                            );
```

**2. First interface implementation:**

The interface represented by the first screenshot is created by `initialize_user_interface()` function:

```
def initialize_user_interface(self):
        """Draw a user interface allowing the user to type
        MySQL server credentials
        """
        self.parent.title("DB operations")       
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.config(background="lavender")

        self.label_user=Tkinter.Label(self.parent,text="DB User: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_password=Tkinter.Label(self.parent,text="DB Password:", anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")

        self.label_user.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)

        self.dbuser=Tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
        self.dbpassword=Tkinter.Entry(self.parent,show="*")

        self.dbuser.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)
        self.dbpassword.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)

        self.connectb=Tkinter.Button(self.parent,text="Log in",font="Helvetica 10 bold",command=self.dbconnexion)
        self.cancelb=Tkinter.Button(self.parent,text="Cancel",command=self.parent.quit,font="Helvetica 10 bold")

        self.connectb.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=Tkinter.W)
        self.cancelb.grid(row=2,column=2)
```

Mainly, I bind the function `dbconnexion()` to the login button `self.connectb`:

```
def dbconnexion(self): 
        """ Pop up a new window if the credentials are the right ones
        """       
        if self.dbuser.get()=="beueradj" and  self.dbpassword.get()=="begueradj":
            # Pop up the new interface if credentials are OK
            self.item_insertion_window()
        else:
            # Loop over the login interface if not
            self.initialize_user_interface()
```

**3. Second interface implementation:**

If the credentials are right, then display insertion window to add the favorite stars to the database. To pop up the new window you need to use [`Tkinter.Toplevel()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) method.

This is done by the function `item_insertion_window()`:

```
def item_insertion_window(self):
        """ Display the stars to add to the database
        Group the stars using radio buttons
        """
        self.new_window=Tkinter.Toplevel(self)
        self.new_window.wm_title("Add my favorite stars")
        self.new_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.new_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.exitb=Tkinter.Button(self.new_window,text="Exit",command=self.new_window.quit)
        self.submitb=Tkinter.Button(self.new_window,text="Submit",command=self.increment_db)
        self.exitb.grid(row=8,column=1)
        self.submitb.grid(row=8,column=0,sticky=Tkinter.W)

        self.v=IntVar()
        self.tvstars=[('YOWERI KAGUTA MUSEVENI', 1), ('KIIZA BESIGYE', 2), 
                      ('AMAAMA JOHN MBABAZI ', 3), ('KARUNGI SHARON', 4), 
                      ('BYAMUKAMA OSCAR', 5), ('MATILDA MOREEN', 6), 
                      ('DUNCANS', 7)]
        self.i=0
        for self.txt, star in self.tvstars:
            self.i=self.i+1
            self.rb=Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.new_window,text=self.txt,variable=self.v,value=star)
            self.rb.grid(row=self.i,column=0,sticky=Tkinter.W)
```

**4. How to get the Tkinter radiobutton text?**

In the official documentation, there is only a way to retrieve the value of the radio button which is picked, but no way is mentioned to get the text (names of the stars) which actually interests us. I did not find any post on StackOverflow dealing with this subject either. My hack is to code a dictionary to map the radio button values to the corresponding star's name using `which_artist()` function:

```
def which_artist(self,radiob):
        """Return star's name
        """
        self.artists = {
                        1:"YOWERI KAGUTA MUSEVENI",
                        2:"KIIZA BESIGYE",
                        3:"AMAAMA JOHN MBABAZI",
                        4:"KARUNGI SHARON",
                        5:"BYAMUKAMA OSCAR",
                        6:"MATILDA MOREEN",
                        7:"DUNCANS",
        }
        return self.artists.get(radiob,"Unknown")
```

This function will be useful in the following step.

**5. Adding your favorite star to the database:**

First, you may save your MySQL server parameters in a configuration file `config.py`, but as our project is small and apparently you are not going to extend it any further in the futur, let's save these credentials within a function itself:

```
self.config = {
                  'user': 'begueradj',
                  'passwd': 'begueradj',
                  'host': '127.0.0.1',
                  'db': 'begueradj',
        }
```

Here is the function that implements the insertion:

```
def increment_db(self):
    """ Insert the selected favorite star into the database.
    """
    self.chosenartist=self.which_artist(self.v.get())
    print self.chosenartist

    self.config = {
              'user': 'begueradj',
              'passwd': 'bregredj',
              'host': '127.0.0.1',
              'db': 'begueradj',
    }
    try:
        self.connecttodb=MySQLdb.connect(**self.config)
    except MySQLdb.Error:
        print"Connexion error"

    self.cursor=self.connecttodb.cursor()

    self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO testtable(starname) VALUES(%s)""",self.chosenartist)

    self.connecttodb.commit()
    self.connecttodb.close()
```

Of course, you will need to change the configuration dictionary `self.config` according to your own settings.

Also, it is more suitable to bind  `self.connecttodb.close()` to the exit button `self.exitb` instead.
**6. The application:**

Here is the full program:

```
'''
Created on Feb 29, 2016

@author: begueradj
'''
import Tkinter
import MySQLdb
from Tkinter import IntVar


class Begueradj(Tkinter.Frame):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''


    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        """Draw a user interface allowing the user to type
        MySQL server credentials
        """
        self.parent.title("DB operations")       
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.config(background="lavender")

        self.label_user=Tkinter.Label(self.parent,text="DB User: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_password=Tkinter.Label(self.parent,text="DB Password:", anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")

        self.label_user.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)

        self.dbuser=Tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
        self.dbpassword=Tkinter.Entry(self.parent,show="*")

        self.dbuser.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)
        self.dbpassword.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)

        self.connectb=Tkinter.Button(self.parent,text="Log in",font="Helvetica 10 bold",command=self.dbconnexion)
        self.cancelb=Tkinter.Button(self.parent,text="Cancel",command=self.parent.quit,font="Helvetica 10 bold")

        self.connectb.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=Tkinter.W)
        self.cancelb.grid(row=2,column=2)

    def item_insertion_window(self):
        self.new_window=Tkinter.Toplevel(self)
        self.new_window.wm_title("Add my favorite stars")
        self.new_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.new_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.exitb=Tkinter.Button(self.new_window,text="Exit",command=self.new_window.quit)
        self.submitb=Tkinter.Button(self.new_window,text="Submit",command=self.increment_db)
        self.exitb.grid(row=8,column=1)
        self.submitb.grid(row=8,column=0,sticky=Tkinter.W)

        self.v=IntVar()
        self.tvstars=[('YOWERI KAGUTA MUSEVENI', 1), ('KIIZA BESIGYE', 2), 
                      ('AMAAMA JOHN MBABAZI ', 3), ('KARUNGI SHARON', 4), 
                      ('BYAMUKAMA OSCAR', 5), ('MATILDA MOREEN', 6), 
                      ('DUNCANS', 7)]
        self.i=0
        for self.txt, star in self.tvstars:
            self.i=self.i+1
            self.rb=Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.new_window,text=self.txt,variable=self.v,value=star)
            self.rb.grid(row=self.i,column=0,sticky=Tkinter.W)


    def which_artist(self,radiob):
        self.artists = {
                        1:"YOWERI KAGUTA MUSEVENI",
                        2:"KIIZA BESIGYE",
                        3:"AMAAMA JOHN MBABAZI",
                        4:"KARUNGI SHARON",
                        5:"BYAMUKAMA OSCAR",
                        6:"MATILDA MOREEN",
                        7:"DUNCANS",
        }
        return self.artists.get(radiob,"Unknown")

    def increment_db(self):
        #print self.v.get()
        self.chosenartist=self.which_artist(self.v.get())
        print self.chosenartist

        self.config = {
                  'user': 'begueradj',
                  'passwd': 'begueradj',
                  'host': '127.0.0.1',
                  'db': 'begueradj',
        }
        try:
            self.connecttodb=MySQLdb.connect(**self.config)
        except MySQLdb.Error:
            print"Connexion error"

        self.cursor=self.connecttodb.cursor()

        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mystars(starname) VALUES(%s)""",self.chosenartist)

        self.connecttodb.commit()
        self.connecttodb.close()



    def dbconnexion(self):        
        if self.dbuser.get()=="begueradj" and  self.dbpassword.get()=="begueradj":
            self.item_insertion_window()
        else:
            self.initialize_user_interface()



def main():
    root=Tkinter.Tk()
    d=Begueradj(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**7. Demo**

I inserted one star through the Tkinter interface. Let's check if that was effective:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM begueradj.mystars;
+----+------------------------+
| id | starname               |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | YOWERI KAGUTA MUSEVENI |
+----+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope this helps.

## UPDATE:

You asked me about how to update but your comments are not clear to me when it comes to understanding the logic of your update statement. So I am answering here only according to the small piece of code your comment shows.

You seem to want to check which radio button is selected through your statement: `self.var.get()` and increment something by 1 (and that is why I do not understand your update statement: so whatever the radiobutton which is pressed you do the same action; which thing means the radio buttons are meaningless).

If you want to do that in the perspective of some mysterious test of your own though, you will need to use [`variable`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/radiobutton.html) option and bind a method to the `command` option for each radiobutton you created.

To use the `variable` option, you will need to run this first:

```
self.v = IntVar()
```

Then, for each radiobutton you set: `variable=self.v` and `command = self.get_radiobutton_id`

The method in question must return the identifier of the selected radiobutton:

```
self defself.get_radiobutton_id(self):
   return v.get()
```

Comment: hi bill,i request for your help again,instead  of the insertion statement i would like to update the table using the value of the radio button. i used "UPDATE tablename SET count = 2 where ID = "self.v.get()"" and it had an error, self.v represent the value of radiobutton.

Comment: what can i change,i will be grateful

Comment: Tell me what is the description of your MySQL table. You seem to have 2 columns: `count` and `ID`  so I do not know why you are storing the names of the stars. **PLEASE edit your question and explain what do you want to update once a radiobutton is selected and submitted: You want to update what by which value?**. That is not clear what you are asking. @ByamukamaOscar

Comment: thanks bill, i was able to work on the above problem but a challenge came in when in updating. i would like to increment  by one in the count column for certain id selected. i tried to use this statement         """update tablename SET count = count +1 where id = %s""",self.v.get().  if you could help me.am really grateful with the help you are rendering

Comment: @ByamukamaOscar check UPDATE